# Creating desktop icons in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, desktop-icons

I don't know how to create desktop icons of applications which have space in their name (like 'Document Viewer')?

Answer (score 1):

Let's create one:

```
~$ cd ~/.local/share/applications
~$ touch my-application.desktop
~$ chmod 700 my-application.desktop
```

Open the file with your favorite text editor and make it look like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=My Application  
Exec=/path-to-executable
Icon=/path-to-icon
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Foo;Bar
```

And here's the result:

[image]